# Order of elements on group

Tags: group-theory

Prove that in any group the orders of $ab$ and of $ba$ are equal. $a,b$ are elements of group.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $(ab)^n = e$ then $a(ba)^nb = ab$.